# How do I delete an element from a database using angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, http

I am currently practicing angular and starting with it, I'm also doing a MEAN stack application, and I'm trying to make a delete function in order to delete an element from the database, but it is not working, I keep getting this error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6mCXy.png)

I also have set `"noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature": false,` since I've read that my current version of angular needs that option disabled in order to work with my code.

I'm trying to delete an element from my database, the reading of the elements works but I cannot delete them. This is my code:

```
export class ListarProductoComponent implements OnInit {

  listProductos: Producto[] =[];
  constructor(private _productoService: ProductoService,
    private toastR: ToastrService){}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.obtenerProductos();
    //throw new Error('Method not implemented.');
  }

  obtenerProductos(){
    this._productoService.getProductos().subscribe(data=>{
      //console.log(data);
    this.listProductos = data;
    }, error=>{
      console.log(error)
    })
  }


  eliminarProducto(id: any) {
      this._productoService['eliminarProducto'](id).subscribe((res: any) => {
      console.log("product deleted")
      this.obtenerProductos();
    }, (error: any) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
  }

}
```

which I'm calling from my html file:

`<i (click)="eliminarProducto(producto._id)" class="fa-solid fa-trash text-danger"></i>` 
So I would like to know what solutions could I use, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There is no method called `eliminarProducto` declared in your `ProductoService`, kindly recheck the `ProductoService` that you have a function declared on it like below!

```
import { of } from 'rxjs/operators';
...
export class ProductoService {
    ...
    eliminarProducto(id: any) {
         // write your code here ignore the below line
         return of(true);
    }
    ...
}
```